# jQuery Masonry is conflicting with my footer

Tags: css, wordpress

I've managed to get jQuery Masonry working on my Wordpress site. But my footer is no longer at the bottom of my page, instead it's been bumped to the top of the page and behind the jQuery Masonry applied content.

Take a look for yourself -- http://camerabooru.com/blog/

I tried to apply "clear:both" to a div tag, but that didn't seem to work. Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I notice that you have a lot of nested duplicates of `<div id="container"></div>` in your HTML. You might want to fix that first.

Comment: Damn, I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. Thank you so much for catching that.

Comment: @KemalFadillah - you should submit an answer - that comment was really helpful - I had duplicate .container classes, too! tx